Cannot load fragments inside Framelayout
it's my first time asking for help on the Internet, usually I find what I'm looking for on the Net or I find the solution by myself but in this case I really don't know why it doesnt work.
Let me explain my problem in precision. I'm programming a OPC UA client on Android and I want to add the possibility to connect to multiple PLCs at the same time.
I have a MainActivity containing a framelayout which will contain a fragment representing the session of one PLC.
This "sessionfragment"  is also constitued of a framelayout and a BottomNavigationView.
This means I will be having multiple instances of this fragment representing one session to one PLC.
But the problem comes when I try to connect to the second PLC.
When connected to the second PLC, the framelayout of the sessionfragment doesn't load the fragments.
Here are some images to make myself clear hopefully, otherwise, don't hesitate to ask me for more information, I really want to get over this. FirstSession SecondSession
I used the debugger and added logs. Everything is going as expected when following the debugger but the results are not there.
It does go (in the second session) on the instruction
fragmentmanager.begintransaction.add(...).show(...).commit();
and doesnt get hidden by other fragments nor gets hidden afterwards by an instruction.
By default when going in a session, only the first fragment is shown, the others are hidden when adding them.
I just see that the Framelayout won't just load the fragments. Only the first session works fine.
I changed the Framelayouts by FragmentContainerview as suggested by Commonsware
App description:
When starting the app, the Connection Fragment is shown in the FragmentContainerView, and when clicking on the button, it discovers the endpoints at the entered IP address. EndpointDiscovery When clicking on the endpoint, it connects to it and if successful, it creates a "session" fragment.
This session fragment contains as said before a FragmentcontainerView container bottomNavigationView and will initalize three fragments : SessionConnected, Dashboard and Browse.
MainActivity Xml :
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
tools:background="@color/darkblue_primary"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:title="OPC UA Client"
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/darkblue_secondary"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/darkblue_secondary"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_sessionTabs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_addSessionTabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_add_24"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_secondary_round"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fc_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bnv_Session"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/darkblue_primary">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_drawer" />
</RelativeLayout></androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

Here's the code when the connection is successful:
                SessionElement sessionElement = (SessionElement) msg.obj;
                successfulDialog.show();
                connectionLoadingDialog.dismiss();
                AuthDialog.dismiss();
                int session_id = sessionTabsList.size();;
                String sessionID = sessionElement.getSession().getSession().getSessionId().getValue().toString();
                sessionTabsList = sendDataToActivity.UpdateSessionList();

                if(sessionTabsList == null)
                {
                    sessionTabsList = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                String session_name = "Session "+ session_id;
                SessionTabs newsession = new SessionTabs(session_name,sessionID,endpoints[position].getEndpointUrl());
                newsession.setCurrentSession(session_id);
                newsession.setSelected(true);
                sessionTabsList.add(newsession);
                sendDataToActivity.SendToActivity(sessionTabsList);

                result.putString("session_id",sessionID);
                result.putString("session_name",session_name);
                result.putParcelable("SessionElement",sessionElement);

                Session_fragment sessionFragment = new Session_fragment();
                sessionFragment.setArguments(result);
                hideConnectionFragment();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fc_MainActivity,sessionFragment,sessionID)
                        .show(sessionFragment)
                        .commit();

The session fragment:
Xml file:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="@color/darkblue_primary"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fc_session"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bnv_Session"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bnv_Session"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/darkblue_secondary"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Base.Theme.Client_OPC_UA"
    app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/colorselect"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/colorselect"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fc_session"
    app:menu="@menu/btmnav_menu" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92" /></LinearLayout>

the code:
public class Session_fragment extends Fragment {
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView,bnv_Dashboard;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Bundle bundle;
SessionElement sessionElement;
String session_id;
String session_name;
Dialog loadingDialog;
Dialog errorDialog;
TextView errorMessage,errorTitle;
String session_Connected, dashboard, browse,dashboard_Liste,dashboard_Diagram;
Session_connected sessionConnected;
Dashboard_fragment dashboard_fragment;
Dashboard_List_fragment dashboard_list_fragment;
Dashboard_Diagram_fragment dashboardDiagramFragment;
Browse_fragment browseFragment;
FragmentContainerView frameLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_session, container, false);
    fragmentManager= getParentFragmentManager();
    bundle= getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        session_name=bundle.getString("session_name");
        session_id=bundle.getString("session_id");
        sessionElement = bundle.getParcelable("SessionElement");
    }
    frameLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.fc_session);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    InitializeLoadingDialog();
    InitializeErrorDialog();
   
    session_Connected = "Session_Connected"+ session_id;
    dashboard = "Dashboard"+ session_id;
    browse = "Browse"+ session_id;
    dashboard_Liste = "Dashboard_Liste" + session_id;
    dashboard_Diagram = "Dashboard_Diagram" + session_id;

    bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.bnv_Session);
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Session && bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()!=R.id.Session) {

            manageFragmentTransaction(R.id.Session);
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Dashboard && bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()!=R.id.Dashboard) {

            manageFragmentTransaction(R.id.Dashboard);
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Browse && bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()!=R.id.Browse) {
            manageFragmentTransaction(R.id.Browse);
        }
        return true;
    });

    CreateSubscription();

    CreateDashboardFragment();
    CreateBrowseFragment();
    CreateSessionConnectFragment();
    return view;
}

private void CreateSessionConnectFragment() {
    Session_connected sessionConnected = new Session_connected();
    bundle.putParcelable("SessionElement",sessionElement);
    sessionConnected.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fc_session, sessionConnected, session_Connected).commit();
    Log.d("FRAGMENT "+session_name, "Creating Session_Connected");
    Log.d("FRAGMENT "+session_name, "Showing Session_Connected");
}

private void CreateBrowseFragment() {
    Browse_fragment browseFragment = new Browse_fragment();
    bundle.putParcelable("SessionElement",sessionElement);
    browseFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fc_session, browseFragment, browse).hide(browseFragment).commit();
    Log.d("FRAGMENT "+session_name, "Creating BrowseFragment");
}
private void CreateDashboardFragment() {
    Dashboard_fragment dashboardFragment = new Dashboard_fragment();
    bundle.putParcelable("SessionElement",sessionElement);
    dashboardFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fc_session, dashboardFragment, dashboard).hide(dashboardFragment).commit();
    Log.d("FRAGMENT "+session_name, "Creating DashboardFragment");
}

}

This may not be related to your problem, but FragmentContainerView replaced FrameLayout for hosting fragments a few years ago.

It's impossible to suggest what could be wrong based on your vague description. You need to show relevant code for how your fragments and layouts are defined / created / updated.
